# How to set expectation on a mocked method which is called inside another mocked method C++

Tags: c++, googlemock

I am a beginner with google testing framework and  have looked up for the solution to this question on SO, but could not find any solutions with respect to C++.  Anyway here is what i am trying to do. I have a state machine(service) which is called inside a client code.

```
  //IStateMachine.h
    class IStateMachine
    {
      public:
      bool Run(const std::string& action) = 0; 
      bool IsTxnValid(const std::string& action)= 0;
    }
    
    //StateMachine.h
    class StateMachine : public IStateMachine
    {
      bool Run(const std::string& action) override;
      bool IsTxnValid(const std::string& action) override;
    
    }
    
    //StateMachine.cpp
    bool StateMachine::IsTxnValid(const std::string& action)
    {
      //Checks whether the given action is valid for the given state.
    }
    
    bool StateMachine::Run(const std::string& action)
    {
       if(IsTxnValid(action))    // #E 
       {
         //Do processing
         return true;
       }
      return false;
    }

    //Client.h contains a class Client which has function called RunService.
    Client
    {
    
      public:
      void RunService();
      std::unique_ptr<IStateMachine> service_; // Initialised to a non null value in either ctr or 
                                              // factory.
    }
    
    //Client.cpp
    bool Client::RunService(std::string&action)
    {
      if(!service_->Run(action)) //Run in turn calls  IsTxnValid().
      {
         return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
```

Now i am writing a test case to test the functioning of `RunService`. I am expecting that if `Client::IsTxnValid(param)` returns false, then so should `RunService`.

I have successfully set up the testing recipe and could get the basic tests running. Here is the relevant test i have written. On running this test the i get the error, that `IsTransitionValid` is never called.

```
TEST_F(ClientTest, RunService)
{                     
    EXPECT_CALL(*p_service, Run("some_action"));  // #A
    // EXPECT_CALL(*p_service, Run(testing::_)).WillOnce(::testing::Return(true)); //#B
    EXPECT_CALL(*p_service,IsTransitionValid(testing::_)).WillOnce(::testing::Return(false));  //#C : This never gets called. 
    EXPECT_EQ(false, x_client->RunService());  
}
```

How do i correctly call `IsTransitionValid` ?

Comment: Remember to add virtual dtor to `IStateMachine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set this expectation. I'd go even further: you should not even depend on the implementation of `Run` in `IStateMachine`: you should only care about what input it is provided with (parameters, checked with matchers) and what output it can return (so basically only the contract between these two classes) and that's the beauty of it!

It is an implementation detail of `StateMachine` class (the real implementation) what is done when `Run` is called. The only thing you need to check in your test is to act upon the result of `Run`. Using triple A rule (arrange, act, assert): you arrange the test case conditions (using `EXPECT_CALL`s), then you act (calling `RunService`) and then you assert (checking the result of `RunService`).

The technical details:
When you create a mock by inheriting from `class Foo`:

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
}
```

By defining:

```
class FooMock : public Foo {
    MOCK_METHOD0( bar, void());
}
```

gmock will add  `bar` (the method to override) and `gmock_bar` (internal detail of gmock) methods to `FooMock` class. `bar` has empty implementation in this case. `FooImpl` and `FooMock` share the interface, but have different implementations - hence no call to `IsTxnValid` is made in `Run`: the mock class just doesn't know (nor care) how `Run` is implemented in `StateMachine`. Remember: in your testcase you interact with `StateMachineMock` and you only care about the interaction with its public interface, the contract between these two classes and how they cooperate together.

That being said, you of course need to utest the `StateMachine` class. It may depend on yet another interfaces in its implementations: that will be tested with different set of mocks. But `Client` should not know about this.